# Recovering deleted/removed .class files from Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, class, build, classpath

How do I recover the deleted `.class` files of my Java project from my Eclipse workspace?

`Project-Clean` does nothing. Also, `Build Automatically` is checked. I have also tried manually rebuilding and it doesn't work. My output folder is `ProjectName/bin` which is blank even after rebuilding.

### Error:

> `Error: Could not find or load main class`

Comment: Rebuild the project...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I already did `Project->Clean` but the class files are still missing.

Comment: Do you have it set to auto-build?

Comment: Note the word 'build'. Class files can always be regenerated. It's the source you don't want to lose.

Comment: @DaveNewton `Build Automatically` is checked.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have `Build Automatically` checked and `Cleaned`.

Comment: You can start a build immediately after cleaning your project...

Comment: By the way, I don't use the *Build Automatically* option.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza How do I rebuild?

Comment: Just write your code and when your project is ready right click on it and select *Build project* option.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I don't see any such option when I right click on my `Java` project in `Eclipse 3.7.2`.

Comment: That's because you have *Build Automatically* set...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I took it off and clicked `Build Project` but there aren't any class files anywhere in the project after doing so, and I still get the same error.

Comment: The classes should be generated in the `bin` folder. Check that folder. IF the classes are there, the problem is probably with the run configuration. Usually when you run your app Eclipse automatically builds if required.

Comment: Then, clean your project. In that same option there's a frame in the bottom part saying to start a build immediately for all the projects or the selected projects.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have build, cleaned, built automatically, cleaned again, restarting, built manually, cleaned, etc, many times, and `bin` is empty and a search for `.class` returns 0 results.

Comment: Ok, try this: right click on your project, select *Properties*, go to Java Build Path, select *Source* tab and check the value of the *Default output folder* input.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It says `src`, but no `bin`. However there's a `bin` in my workspace which used to hold my class files (but they got deleted).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Also, in my `.classpath` it has `<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>`

Comment: Again, check the value of the *Default output folder* input. In my projects, it is `<project_name>`/bin. Looks like this can be your problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It is the `bin` folder, sorry. i.e., it is `ProjectName/bin`.

Comment: Ok, there is another option and is called `javac`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Could this have somethign to do with `svn`? After I `svn import` all my projects, two of my `bin` folders got wiped and can't be recovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it was a bug. Here was the steps I followed to fix it, I am not certain about whether any given step is necessary but it worked:

- Delete .eclipse folder.
- Open Eclipse with the same workspace, now SVN will be disconnected.
- Delete every .svn folder from workspace using `find . -type d -name .svn -exec rm -rf {} \;`.
- Turn off build automatically. Building the individual broken project still won't work but what does work is to `Project -> Clean`, then at the bottom there will be a button box allowing you to check `Build  only the selected projects`. Have the broken project selected and build successfully.